# ruby net/ssh not using user in ssh config

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ssh

i am trying to ssh to my aws instance using net/ssh. but it always logins as different user from what i currently wants.
my ssh `config` file has the following

```
Host haseeb_*
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
User eqx
Hostname example.com
```

but when ssh into the device `haseeb_01` i am logging in as `www-data`.

my ruby code (stripped some part to reduce complexity)

```
require 'net/ssh'
begin
  Net::SSH.start(host) do |ssh|
     output = ssh.exec! "stat -c %s #{path}"
     unless (true if Float(output) rescue false)
        raise 'file not found'
     end
  end
rescue =>e
  logger.error("Error: #{e}")
end
```

Comment: No. It does not use OpenSSH configuration. It has its own.

Comment: @Jakuje if so, why it correctly addresses haseeb_01 to the correct  sub domain i am using

Comment: Maybe you have it also in the `/etc/hosts`? Or it supports only some subset?

Comment: @Jakuje http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/Net/SSH/Config.html read

Comment: Well ... obviously there are not mentioned nor `Host` block or `Match` blocks.